# Deleting the head of a circular linked list results in having random integers inside it's items

Tags: c++

I'm making a circular linked list for storing books.Here I am trying to delete a node from a linked list. When I'm deleting nodes other than head, no problem, but when it comes to head node, it can't but makes the integer numbers stored in it random.

```
if (head == current) {
    head = head->next;
    delete current;
    current = NULL;
    break;
}

else {
    prev->next = current->next;
    delete current;
    current = NULL;
    cout << "Book " << bookId << "has been deleted." << endl;
    break;
}
```

For example, I created two book item called "cs" and "aa"   and deleted them. The result is:

```
 BookId    BookName        Year      Status
 7710128   cs              7672960
```

SO it deleted the second one, but the head node is can't deleted and it's integers have random values.
Here is the implementation of booknode

```
 struct bookNode
 {
      int bookId,year;
      string bookName;
      bookNode *next;
 };
```

I solved the problem by implementing a tail and set it next to new head.

Comment: Start with proper indentation. Then provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: you need to put `head->next` in a `temp` variable, delete `head`, then set `temp` as `head`

Comment: Where are you making the last node point to the new `head`?

Comment: where is `prev` declaration in your struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should delete the first node of your linked list if `head` is a pointer to your first node:

```
bookNode* temp;     
temp = head->next;
delete head;
head = temp;
```

But, you need to make sure that the `next` pointer of your last node is pointing to this new head(which basically should `= head`) and that the `previous` pointer of this new head is pointing back to that last node.

You can do it by stating this:

```
booknode* tempNext;
booknode* tempPrevious;
tempNext = head->next;
tempPrevious = head->previous;

delete head;

tempNext->previous = tempPrevious;
temoPrevious->next = tempNext;

head = tempNext;
```